# how to write where clause to select multiple values for same column in flask mysql with checkbox

Tags: python, html, mysql, flask

Flask code of python

```
cursor = conn.cursor()
            amin=request.form.getlist('interest')
            str1 = ','.join(amin)
            cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM emp_vehical_report WHERE Location IN (%s)",[str1])
            vehical_details=cursor.fetchall()
            rendered=render_template('Download.html',list=vehical_details,x=str1)
```

I need to  get all values from database with the checkedbox location
But I get it for only one location and not for other selected checkboxes

basically [str1] has values ['Building1,Building2'] if 2 checkboxes selected
of which query doesnt work
else [str] has ['Building1'] if 1 checkbox is selected and it works
Help me with multiple checkboxes
Thanks in advance

HTML code

```
 <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Building1" name="interest" value="Building1">
    <label for="Building1">Building 1</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Building2" name="interest" value="Building2">
    <label for="Building2">Building 2</label>
  </div>
  <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Building3" name="interest" value="Building3">
    <label for="Building3">Building 3</label>
  </div>
   <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Building4" name="interest" value="Building4">
    <label for="Building4">Building 4</label>
  </div>
   <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="Building5" name="interest" value="Building5">
    <label for="Building5">Building 5</label>
  </div>
   <div>
    <input type="checkbox" id="AL" name="interest" value="AL">
    <label for="All Locations">All Locations</label>
  </div>
```

Comment: Print `str1` and see if it's what you need

Comment: yuxiaoy yes it is what i need but 
```
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM emp_vehical_report WHERE Location IN (%s)",[str1])
```
it gives error if I write str1 instead of [str1]